# Peak open-circuit current and applied voltage of transformer function

Tags: voltage, current, transformer

I know that the back-EMF equation tells shows that the peak flux density is proportional to the AC supply voltage. But what is the explanation for that the open-circuit current increases non linearly whereas the applied voltage increases linearly (I did notice this while I was performing an experiment)? Does it have to do with the B-H curve  or something?

As a consequence (I guess), the magnetizing reactance did change with the change in voltage. What physical effects cause this?? Shouldn't it be constant?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have to do with the B-H curve or something?

Yes. It is magnetic saturation as illustrated by the B-H curve or magnetization curve. A detailed explanation can be easily found on the internet.

Comment: But could you please simplify the whatever the internet says as I am really new to transformers?

Comment: No. We are here to answer specific questions about more detailed source material that you may find, not to rewrite text material. You should be able to find explanations with illustrations presented in several different ways. This format is not  well suited to do that.